# String whitespace

Tags: c#, string

I have a string that will have multiple whitespace characters in it and I'm wanting to seperate each word by 1 whitespace character. Say if the string is "Hi! My name  is   troy        and      i love                 waffles!", I want to trim that so it is "Hi! My name is troy and I love waffles!". How would I do this?

Comment: Do you mean whitespace (tabs, spaces, and other whitespace characters), or just spaces?

Comment: Well, I meant just spaces. But the other guys regular expression worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the regular expression `\s+` (one or more whitespace) with the [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx) method from the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s+", " ");
```

If you just want to replace spaces you can change the "`\s`" to a space "":

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @" +", " ");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string.Join(" ","Hi! My name is troy        and      i love                 waffles!"
    .Split(new char[]{' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select (s => s.Trim()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var input = "Hi! My name is troy        and      i love                 waffles!";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\s{2,}", string.Empty);
Console.WriteLine(output); //Hi! My name is troy and I love waffles!
```